# Append to PATH on Azure Devops?

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines-build-task

I need to append to the PATH environment variable on an Azure Devops pipeline. I have tried running a script to do it but it does not work:

```
- script: |
echo '##vso[task.setvariable variable=PATH]${PATH}:some/path/'
```

This fails to set the path and also results in subsequent scripts failing with the following:

```
##[error]Unable to locate executable file: 'bash'. Please verify either the file path exists or the file can be found within a directory specified by the PATH environment variable. Also check the file mode to verify the file is executable.
```

What do I need to do in order to set this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Got it, it was a simple syntax error

```
echo '##vso[task.setvariable variable=path]$(PATH):/dir/to/whatever'
```

I'd used {} instead of ().

Comment: That is a horrible error message to show when that was the case

Answer (score 19):

There is a special logging command for this:

```
echo '##vso[task.prependpath]some\path'
```

See more info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a variable in the path you can use this snipped

```bash
echo "##vso[task.prependpath]${MY_VAR}"
```

When you use single quotes variables (`'`), variables will not be resolved, therefore you have to use double quotes (`"`)